# Could I have appended this vector of characters without using apply?

Tags: r, apply, paste

I recently generated this output:

```
> RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral(c("G","R","S","H"),2)
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,] "G"  "R" 
 [2,] "G"  "S" 
 [3,] "G"  "H" 
 [4,] "R"  "G" 
 [5,] "R"  "S" 
 [6,] "R"  "H" 
 [7,] "S"  "G" 
 [8,] "S"  "R" 
 [9,] "S"  "H" 
[10,] "H"  "G" 
[11,] "H"  "R" 
[12,] "H"  "S"
```

and my goal was to transform it in to this:

```
G vs R
G vs S
G vs H
R vs G
R vs S
R vs H
S vs G
S vs R
S vs H
H vs G
H vs R
H vs S
```

My ultimate solution was `writeLines(apply(RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral(c("G","R","S","H"),2),1,function(x) paste(x,collapse = " vs ")))`, but this is not what I was after. In particular, `writeLines` prints the output rather than returning it and I see no reason why I needed to use `writeLines` to get the desired line breaks (to my knowledge, adding a \n argument to `paste` should've been enough, but in practice it did nothing).

However, my biggest surprise of all was that I needed to use `apply`. If I'm not mistaken, `paste` is already vectorized, so either `paste` on its own or `sapply` with `paste` should have been sufficient. Was there any way to achieve my goal without using apply? There's probably a tidyverse one-liner for this, but my preference is to see an idiomatic base R solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a function in `permuteGeneral` :

```
unlist(RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral(c("G","R","S","H"),2, 
       FUN = function(x) paste(x, collapse  = ' vs ')))

#[1] "G vs R" "G vs S" "G vs H" "R vs G" "R vs S" "R vs H"
#[7] "S vs G" "S vs R" "S vs H" "H vs G" "H vs R" "H vs S"
```

If the data is already generated we can use

```
data <- RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral(c("G","R","S","H"),2)
paste(data[, 1], data[, 2], sep = ' vs ')
```

and if there are many columns and we don't want to write them individually.

```
do.call(paste, c(data.frame(data), sep = ' vs '))
```

Comment: Very nice, and probably what I'll use in the future, but my question was stated with the assumption that the data from permuteGeneral had already been generated.